# Swapping linked list items issue C

Tags: c, list, pointers, swap

i'm trying to invert the "info" field of the in a list like the one below

```
struct nodo {
    int info;
    struct nodo *next;
    struct nodo *prev;
    } ;
typedef struct nodo nodo;
```

Here is the main, the two output should be the original list of n mebmers, and the inverted list (First value go n , second n-1 and so on)

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    struct nodo *p;

    p = CreateList();
    PrintList(p);
    IvertList(p);
    Printlist(p);


    return 0;
    }
```

Here is InvertList(): (Count() function just returns dimension of the list, i know it is a messy way but i'm focused on result for now)

```
void InvertList (struct nodo *p) {

int tmp = 0, num = 0, i = 0;

    num = (Count(p));
    tmp = num;

    for (i=1; i!=tmp; i++) {
        Swap(p,num);
        num--;
        }
   }
```

And here is Swap(), this should bring a value (int info) to the first place of the list, to the last swapping with each:

```
void Swap (struct nodo *p, int n) {

    int *tmp1 = NULL, *tmp2 = NULL;
    int i;
    for ( i = 1;  i != n && p != NULL; i++) {
        tmp1 = &p->info;
        p = p->succ;
        tmp2 = &p->info;
        p->info = *tmp1;
        p->prec->info = *tmp2;

       }
    }
```

Now the output i got printed is:

```
Value: 1
Value: 2
Value: 3
Value: 4
Value: 5
Value: 1
Value: 1
Value: 1
Value: 1
Value: 1
```

Where the last 5 values should be 5-4-3-2-1.

Answer (score 1):

The bug(s) in your code not withstanding, you're not reversing your physical list at all, which I can all-but-guarantee is the point of the exercise in the first place.

Inversion of a linked list means all the pointers switch directions and the old tail becomes the new head. You seem to be avoiding that and trying to swap node info values instead.

To invert your list using simple pointer swapping:

```
// note head pointer passed by address
void InvertList(node **pp)
{
    node *cur = *pp;
    while (cur)
    {
        node *tmp = cur->prev;
        cur->prev = cur->next;
        cur->next = tmp;
        *pp = cur;
        cur = cur->prev;
    }
}
```

And invoke from `main()` as:

```
InvertList(&p);
```

Note that **no info values need be swapped, copied, etc.** The node pointers simply switch direction and their enumeration will start at the other end. A full working example appears below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};
typedef struct node node;

static void PrintList(const node *head)
{
    while (head)
    {
        printf("%d: this=%p, prev=%p, next=%p\n",
               head->info, head, head->prev, head->next);
        head = head->next;
    }
}


static void InvertList(node **pp)
{
    node *cur = *pp;
    while (cur)
    {
        node *tmp = cur->prev;
        cur->prev = cur->next;
        cur->next = tmp;
        *pp = cur;
        cur = cur->prev;
    }
}

int main()
{
    node *prev = NULL, *head = NULL, **pp = &head;

    for (int i=1; i<=5; ++i)
    {
        *pp = malloc(sizeof **pp);
        (*pp)->info = i;
        (*pp)->prev = prev;
        prev = *pp;
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
    }
    *pp = NULL;

    PrintList(head); // prints 1,2,3,4,5
    InvertList(&head);
    PrintList(head); // prints 5,4,3,2,1
}
```

**Output** (addresses vary, obviously)

```
1: this=0x1001054b0, prev=0x0, next=0x1001054d0
2: this=0x1001054d0, prev=0x1001054b0, next=0x1001054f0
3: this=0x1001054f0, prev=0x1001054d0, next=0x100105510
4: this=0x100105510, prev=0x1001054f0, next=0x100105530
5: this=0x100105530, prev=0x100105510, next=0x0
5: this=0x100105530, prev=0x0, next=0x100105510
4: this=0x100105510, prev=0x100105530, next=0x1001054f0
3: this=0x1001054f0, prev=0x100105510, next=0x1001054d0
2: this=0x1001054d0, prev=0x1001054f0, next=0x1001054b0
1: this=0x1001054b0, prev=0x1001054d0, next=0x0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in your `Swap` fcn:

```
p->info       = *tmp1;
p->prev->info = *tmp2;
```

But what are `tmp1` and `tmp2` at that time?  Well, after we advanced `p`, `tmp1` points at `p->prev->info`, while `tmp2 = &p->info;`  So we could rewrite these assignments in effect as:

```
p->info       = p->prev->info;
p->prev->info = p->info;
```

So, we could rewrite them again, in effect, as:

```
p->info       = p->prev->info;
p->prev->info = p->prev->info;
```

So, the second assignment doesn't change anything in effect.  Therefore, the first call to `Swap` in `InvertList` takes the value of the first element (1) and sets all the values in the list equal to it.  The subsequent calls to `Swap` act similarly but have no effect as the list already contains all 1's.

Here's a simple way to rewrite `Swap`:

```
void Swap(struct nodo *p, int n) 
{
    if (n <= 1)
      return;

    int tmp = p->info;

    for (int i = 1; i != n; ++i, p = p->next) 
      p->info = p->next->info;

    p->info = tmp;
}
```

Note, however, that the way you've written `InvertList` is doing theta(n^2) work.  The first loop iteration shifts the first element n-1 spots, the second iteration shifts the first element n-2 spots, the third iteration shifts the first element n-3 spots, and so on, down to shifting the first element 1 spot.  So, you end up doing something like n * (n - 1) / 2 total shifts to reverse the list.

A linked list can be reversed / inverted in theta(n) work.  See if you can figure out a better way to do this.  If you had a pointer to both the beginning and the end of the list (which you often want anyway), then you could do something similar to reversing the characters in a string, for example.